# Rails 6 ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController issue after installing Config gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

Rails version: 6.0.2.1

Ruby version: 2.7.0p0

I added `gem 'config'` (https://github.com/rubyconfig/config) to my Rails 6 project, ran `bundle install`, and `rails g config:install`. Everything appeared to install correctly.

I can start the rails server successfully but when I actually open the app in the browser this lovely error (see below) is outputted in the Rails log and also outputted on to the page.

I have reproduced this on a fresh rails app following the same steps. However, this error only happened once a `before_action` was added to ApplicationController. **Also, when I remove everything from my original projects ApplicationController, the error does not occur.**

```
2020-05-02 15:34:53 -0700: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController>
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `class_eval'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/lib/action_text/content.rb:132:in `<main>'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `instance_exec'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:607:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `catch'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block in default_terminator'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:119:in `complete!'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `ensure in block in run!'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `block in run!'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:77:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/Users/sslade/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**Update:**
Disabling actiontext resolves this issue. However, it is not not ideal especially if I decide I want to use it in the future.

**config/application.rb**

```
# require 'rails/all'
require 'rails'
require 'active_record/railtie'
require 'active_storage/engine'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'action_cable/engine'
require 'action_mailbox/engine'
# require 'action_text/engine'
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

Comment: Might be related to this issue... https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37183

Comment: @dbugger It definitely seems very relevant! However, in my situation it should be relying on regular web processing. So depending on ApplicationController should not be a problem. Unless the gem I added is doing processing before ApplicationController is ready...

Answer (score 0):

After disabling ActionText, Rails let me know of some errors in ApplicationController. There was a line where I had `=||` instead  of`||=`. After fixing that syntax, my app loaded as expected.

I then added ActionText back in afterwards to see if it would load: it did! So it was in fact a simple syntax mistake in ApplicationController but for some reason I was getting an ActionText error instead the syntax error.

If there is any follow up as to why this issue may have occurred, please update this thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39130